# How to extract negative sentences using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have data such as:

## Example 1

```
Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is lots of other stuff going on.
There is no aspiration.
Conclusion: Appearances are consistent with achalasia.
```

## Example 2

```
Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is no evidence of achalasia here.
There is no aspiration.
Conclusion: Normal study
```

## Example 3

```
Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is no reflux.
There is no aspiration.
Conclusion: Possible achalasia
```

I want to get rid of the words between `'no' and achalasia` but restricted to one line so that with the examples above I get

## Example 1

```
Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is lots of other stuff going on.
There is no aspiration.
Conclusion: Appearances are consistent with achalasia.
```

## Example 2

```
Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is.
There is no aspiration.
Conclusion: Normal study
```

## Example 3

```
Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is no reflux.
There is no aspiration.
Conclusion: Possible achalasia
```

To do this (in R) I am using the following regular expression:

```
[Nn]o.*[Aa]chalasia.*?(\\.\\n|\\.$)
```

However with this I get:

## Example 1

```
Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is lots of other stuff going on.
There is no
```

## Example 2

```
Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is no aspiration.
Conclusion: Normal study
```

## Example 3

```
Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is no reflux.
There is no
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

`/(?i)\s?no\s.*achalasia/`

It shouldn't match across lines.

In Ruby:

```
string.gsub!(/(?i)\s?no\s.*achalasia/, '')
```

Comment: So really the part Im interested in is between no and achalasia as the bit before this changes (ie There is...). What stops the match across newlines here?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following *regex* :

```
\bno(.*?)achalasia\b
```

**Ruby**

```
re = /\bno(.*?)achalasia\b/
str = 'Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is lots of other stuff going on.
There is no aspiration.
Conclusion: Appearances are consistent with achalasia.
Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is no evidence of achalasia here.
There is no aspiration.
Conclusion: Normal study
Barium swallow : There is slow transit to the stomach.
There is no reflux.
There is no aspiration.
Conclusion: Possible achalasia
There is no evidence of achalasia here.'

# Print the match result
str.match(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so I figured this out. The issue is not the regex but rather the fact that when using gsub with R for regular expressions you you use the option perl=T

I then used `[Nn]o.*[Aa]chalasia.*?(\\.|$)`

which did the trick